# How to store Hex string in an Integer variable in android???

Tags: java, android, image-processing, rgb

In the following code intArray[i] stores RGB values of pixels in hex format(eg:0xffff0000)   .... The method hsvToRgb() gives bak an integer value of RGB (eg:15777252) but i need back the rgb value in the original hex format after changes. 
The second line gives me that but its a string ....What do i do to store this string value back into the array? ... please help me.

```
       int disco = hsvToRgb(hsv);

       hexColor = String.format("0x%06X", (0xffffff & disco));
       intArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(disco), 16);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "hex format" integer versus a "decimal format" integer.  The bit/byte representation of the value is the same.  For example, the decimal value `15,777,252` is the hex value `0xF0BDE4`.  (You can use Google to convert: [search "15777252 in hex"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=15777252+in+hex)).

You can use the `disco` value directly.  If you want to print it out in a hex representation, use [`Integer.toHexString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29).

Regarding the format.  Think of it like this ...  The computer represents the value as a series of bits.  By way of example, let's pick a random number and represent it using 8 bits: `01110101`.  Using a bit string to represent bigger numbers would get very long very quickly, so hexadecimal is often used.  The hex equivalent is: `65`.  By convention, we usually precede the value by `0x` when it's in hex.  That gives us `0x65`.  Non-programmers tend to deal more naturally in base 10 however (rather than base 16).  The same number in base 10 is `101`.

You can see this with some code:

```
final int value = 0x65;                            // we can declare it in hex
final int sameValue = 101;                         // or in decimal

System.out.println(value);                         // output in base 10; prints "101"
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(value));    // output in base 16; prints "65"
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value)); // output in base 2; prints "1100101"

System.out.println(""+(value == sameValue));       // prints "true"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . I understand now. Im trying to change the HSV values of specific pixels ....                    using  android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv) , i converted the rgb colors to HSV but converting the modified hsv value back to rgb is causing me trouble :( ... is there ne way to do this in android?